# null check if statement isn't working in java

Tags: java, if-statement, null, conditional-statements

i want to check a instanciate object is null in java when i press enter, i have a class with a constructor and i pass a parameter

```
private String codigo;
    private String nombre;
    private String descripcion;
    private String foto;
    private String stock;

public Producto(String codigo) {
   this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
}
/*then getters and setters


*/


//this is in a java form 
private void txtCodigoProductoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
Producto producto = new Producto(txtCodigoProducto.getText());
System.out.println(producto);


if (producto==null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No existe este producto");

        }else{
            lbl1.setText(producto.getNombre());
            lbl2.setText(producto.getDescripcion());
         }

}
```

System.out.println(producto) shows null when i press enter since i wrote an incorrect number so all the attributes of producto are null but then why it doesn't check if is null and doesn't show me the the message dialog? 
I change the condition to one of the attributes since all of them are null:

```
if (producto.getStock()==null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No existe este producto");

        }else{
            lbl1.setText(producto.getNombre());
            lbl2.setText(producto.getDescripcion());
         }
}
```

and it worked and showed me the messageDialog, so why producto == null doesn't work?

Comment: `Producto producto = new Producto(txtCodigoProducto.getText());` - obviously not null.

Comment: Note that `null` and an empty string (`""`) are two very different things.  And I don't think `getText()` will ever return `null`, though it will certainly return an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, a variable of object type, such as `producto` in your example, can either refer to an object, or be null.  If you set it to an object, like you did when you wrote `producto = new Producto(txtCodigoProducto.getText());` then it's not null any more.

Inside an object there can be other variables, called fields.  Each of these (if it has object type) can also either refer to an object, or be null.  The object that you created with `new Producto(txtCodigoProducto.getText());` has five variables inside.  The one called `codigo` refers to an object.  The other four are null.

Checking `if (producto.getStock()==null)` will only work if `producto` refers to an object.  It (presumably) asks that object for the value of its `stock` field, then checks whether that value is null, or refers to an object.

That's a completely different check from `if(producto == null)`, which only checks the `producto` variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

`Producto producto = new Producto(...);` absolutely **guarantees** that `producto` is not `null`. `System.out.println(producto)` therefore calls `producto.toString()`.

It is the **`toString()`** implementation of `Producto` that returns `null` or the text `"null"`.

`if (producto == null)` is a meaningless statement, since `producto` cannot be `null`.